# What are some things Mono is not a good fit for?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, mono

I've started your typical web project from scratch using the Mono platform. You know, web services, a UI, MySQL database, all that. I've heard around the net that it's not a picture-perfect implementation of the .Net platform, but so far I can't find anything it's not good at. I see the odd "Not Implemented" pop up in intellesense, but haven't run into any snags or dead ends.

Have you hit a brick wall with a .Net feature that's not implemented in Mono?

Comment: Mono for web projects is good enough (it doesn't have WebParts e.g bu who uses it?) Even proprietary frameworks like DXperience from DevExpress, that doesn't officially support it, work pretty well from what I tested. Silverlight has limmited support, it's not recommended, but I don't think you are considering it as "web project".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, the guys working on Mono have pretty much feature completed their version of ASP.NET 2.0. Now I know they have been working on getting the .NET 3.5 things like LINQ and such implimented, but I'm not too sure how far they've gotten with that. I do know that working the desktop has been a little more difficult and they've been working to get a few of the desktop specific namespaces worked out like System.Windows.Forms.

[Here is an article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cross-platform/mono-merta.aspx) that dives a little bit deeper into the whole Mono setup. It's a little old, but has a lot of code and descriptions to digest.

Good luck, and hope Mono works out for your project.

Answer (score 1):

License is a problem, noncompacting GC is another problem, there is no WPF, WF, Entity Framework, has only basic WCF, MonoDevelop has a long way to race with Eclipse/VS.Net, mod_mono isn't stable or perfect as tomcat/IIS, I couldn't find any high traffic site using it...but, You probably will not face with a serious problem, if your project isn't enterprise level. C# is probably the best architected language ever and evolving fast. .Net framework is far better than jdk in my opinion and mono people working hard, but there are other problems as I said; another choice is Java. Java has the mature / rack-solid state of art projects like Terracotta, Hibernate (ported to .net), Ehcache, Compass,... but some people say that Sun is out of money and Java isn't evolving for years (as a language) so began to die,...

I think the most important thing is finishing the job done right and on time. Select the technology which you know best and like most and don't waste your time by looking back. It'll be not a problem until your project grows too much.

Cheers,